# How to tell java application to connect to specific Axon server gPRC port?

Tags: axon

in our Spring Boot project we run Axon server in Docker on port gRPC 8125.
How to tell application which is configured by AxonAutoConfiguration to use Axon server port 8125, instead of default 8124? I couldn't find anything on the matter.
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just specify a property in `application.properties` file located in your resources:

```
axon.axonserver.servers=localhost:8125
```

Comment: For the full list of properties, you can check their docs at https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/axon-server/administration/admin-configuration/configuration#configuration-properties

Comment: @LucasCampos The link you provided contains configuration for the Axon Server application itself. But OP was asking about tweaking configuration of separate Spring Boot application, which is trying to connect to Axon Server. I think that these are different configurations properties. Or have I overlooked something? :

Comment: You are right Michal, thanks for pointing that out! Feel free to disregard my message in this case =)